# Subgraph induced by negative cycles detected by Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

What is known about the properties of the subgraph induced by the negative cycles are defined by the predecessor relation that is established during the execution of the Bellman-Ford algorithm and arcs $(u,v)$ satisfying  $\mathrm{dist}(u)+\omega(u,v)\lt\mathrm{dist}(v)$ after its execution?

Assuming that the negative cycles are vertex-disjoint, is it true that re-running the Bellman-Ford algorithm after the weights of negative-cycle arcs have been multiplied by $-1$, no negative cycles will be found in that 2nd execution?

Comment: Manfred, I do not quite understand how the multiplication by -1 comes in? Why does this multiplication take place?

Comment: @MaryS. it is because the negative edges resemble edges in the non-optimal matching $M$, whose direction has been inverted and their weight multiplied by $-1$. After having detected a negative cycle, we exchange edges in $M$ corresponding to the negative edges on that cycle with the positive ones on that cycle, reducing $|M|$. For the next iteration we must **undo** the inversion of direction and negation of weights for edges removed from $M$ and **do** it for the added ones and, and the reason for multiplying with $-1$ is that **do**ing it twice amounts to **undo**ing it.

Comment: Let me think about it! When you say "the negative edges resemble edges in the non-optimal matching": what does the word "resemble" mean here?

Comment: I should have said negative arcs, because the shortest path problem instance that is generated from the original graph and a matching, consists of directed *arcs*, whereas the *edges* in the original graph are undirected.